# What is the best way to make knowledge base?

Tags: joomla-3.x, recommended-practices

I want to make a knowledge base section for my Joomla site.

Is there a good way to make it?

In my case :

1. I have a hyperlink text called "Knowledge Base".
2. When I click on it, it will open a new page with a list of articles (title only with linkable to its content) of every categories in one parent category.
3. The thing is, I don't make menu item for that list of articles page in my main menu. So, I follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQ9gMRlCiEQ) step.
4. But I got problem whenever I open one of the article. The list of the article always shown in the page.

So, is there a good other solution to make knowledge base section? I don't bother to make it manually or using some extensions.

Comment: Could you send a URL of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @iamrobert maybe `mysite.com/parentcategory/` for the list of articles (currently using 'Articles - Category' module in hidden menu item like in the example video) , and `mysite.com/parentcategory/category/article` while on the article page.

Comment: Have you tried any of these off the shelf extensions? http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension?searchall=faq&filter%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=&filter%5Bcore_catid%5D=&filter%5Bincludes%5D=&filter%5Bversions%5D=&filter%5Btype%5D=&filter%5Bhasdemo%5D=&order=&filter%5Bnewupdated%5D=&filter%5Bscore%5D=&filter%5Bfavourites%5D=&dir=DESC&limitstart=0&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1

Comment: Why don't you use FAQs-type of extensions? Phil dropped the link to the relative JED category above. - I would suggest the [**Minitek Faq Book**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/directory-a-documentation/faq/minitek-faq-book) as a free and full featured solution, to produce knowledge base section on your site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's possible to do it with Joomla core articles, or by using a CCK type of component for this, I think it will be easier to use one of the ready-made extensions that provide [**FAQ/Knowledge Base solutions**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension?searchall=faq&filter%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=&filter%5Bcore_catid%5D=&filter%5Bincludes%5D=&filter%5Bversions%5D=&filter%5Btype%5D=&filter%5Bhasdemo%5D=&order=&filter%5Bnewupdated%5D=&filter%5Bscore%5D=&filter%5Bfavourites%5D=&dir=DESC&limitstart=0&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1).

You will get the required functionality and features out of the box.
One of the extensions I usually use is the [**Minitek FAQ Book**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/directory-a-documentation/faq/minitek-faq-book).

It's free and has all the features you may need for an effective and good looking Knowledge Base section on your website.

Comment: It's great! I have already tried it. And maybe I will use this, BUT, it seems I can't hide author info and published date for each article. It is always shown below the articles. Actually, I don't want publish the author info and the date. Do you know how to disable it?

Comment: @adadion These can be controlled through component's configuration (top right button when in component). Then go to FAQs tab and there you can adjust.

Comment: Sigh, I didn't even notice that there is Configuration button, lol. Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked through the JED http://extensions.joomla.org/ to see if anything meets your needs?

Here is a good KB option I've used on several sites http://www.freestyle-joomla.com

If you really want to develop your own, it sounds like you need to look at the development tutorials. https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component

Depending on your development experience you should consider starting with a component builder. https://www.component-creator.com